# who implements the Iterator interface

Tags: java, collections

Now the Collection Interface  has a iterator interface ,collection interface is implemented by Abstract list,Abstract set etc ,but who implements the Iterator interface?

Comment: You can look in the source code of the collection classes, which you can find in the file `src.zip` in your JDK installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

There are many classes which provides implementation for iterator. And [**Javadoc**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) have the information about it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All Known Implementing Classes:

```
BeanContextSupport.BCSIterator, EventReaderDelegate, Scanner
```

Source : [Iterator Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

> Note : Always use [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) for information about all Java classes.

Answer (score 0):

AbstractSet and AbstractList are abstract classes.They are not bound to implement all the methods present in their respective interfaces.

Iterator is implemented by concrete classes Like ArrayList,Vector,LinkedList,HashSet,TreeSet because order and the way iterator is done depends on the concrete class type.

Answer (score 0):

Any class which implements `Iterator` interface or any of the interface which implements `Iterator` interface will definitely provide an implementation for all the methods in `Iterator` interface unless it is marked as `abstract` class. There is no rule that `abstract` class shouldn't provide implementation. They also can..

Here is sample code for abstract class which doesn't necessarily need to implement the methods in Iterator interface. But, they also can..

```
 abstract  class TestAbstractIterator implements Iterator<String>{

  }
```

The below is a normal class, which should compulsarily implement the methods in Iterator interface

```
 class TestIterator implements Iterator<String>{

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String next() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

  }
```

Example : `java.util.Scanner` is one of the finest examples of `Iterator` concrete implementations. it implements `Iterator<String>`

Hope it clarifies!

Comment: Uhm, even abstract classes can implement it

Comment: yes, i will just change it.. but not compulsarily right.

Answer (score 0):

As it was already written, there are thousands of implementations.

You gave the example of the `AbstractList` as an implementation of `Collection` (which nis a bit incomplete because it is still abstract and doesn't fully implement the interface) and if you had a look a src.zip, you would see that there is uses its own implementation of `Iterator`.

This implmentation cannot be instanciated in another class because it is **private**! (Please note that this is not the only case.)